# A simple example of a recursively defined sequence that does not have an explicit form.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I believe that not every recursively defined sequence has a closed form, but searching here and elsewhere has not yielded examples. Can anyone give an example (that high school students could understand) or contradict my belief? Thanks!

Comment: [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) are such an example.

Comment: Also depends on your definition of closed form.  (IMO, the harmonic numbers are wonderfully beautiful)

Comment: Closed form is a bit fuzzy. Even recursive can mean different concepts (thinking of primitive and $\mu$ recursion).

Comment: Obligatory link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression

Comment: @Reveillark I guess [Dobinski's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula) $$B_n=\frac1e\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^n}{k!}$$ doesn't count as an explicit formula?

Comment: @bof I was not aware of that formula.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I think the logistic map is the kind of example I was looking for.